# How to reinitizlize libpam-krb5 for kerberos

Tags: kerberos

I ran the following:
`sudo apt install libpam-krb5`

I made a mistake going through the wizard. How do i reinitialize the wizard? I tried `sudo apt purge libpam-krb5` and then reinstalled and the wizzard still didn't come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package does not have any configuration of its own; it installs and uses a common Kerberos library. To change Kerberos client configuration, use `dpkg-reconfigure krb5-config` or just edit `/etc/krb5.conf`.

To select which PAM modules to enable, use `dpkg-reconfigure libpam-runtime`.